# how to update specific index of integer array in functional component setState in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

first i make price int array and store int numbers in hook only once then i want to update specific index of that price array in update value but didnt able to update setPrice specific index instead it return  me to array with only one value but i want all values with updated index value like [0,3,4,5,6] update id 1 then in my logic multiply by 2 it should do [0,6,4,5,6] but it return me only [6]

```
import React, {useEffect,useState,useContext } from 'react';
import {Cartlist} from '../Global/CartContext.js';
const Cart=()=>{
  const {ShoppingCart,totalprice,quantity,dispatch} = useContext(Cartlist);
  const [price,setPrice]=useState([])
  const Style={
    width:'100px',
    height: '100px',
  }
  useEffect(()=>{
    ShoppingCart.map((products)=>{
      setPrice(prev=>[...prev,products.price]);
    })
  },[])
  const updatevalue=(e)=>{
    ShoppingCart.map((products)=>{
      if (e.target.id===products.id){
          setPrice(price=>price[products.id-1]*2);
      }
  })
  }
  return (
    <div className='container'>
      {ShoppingCart.length > 0 ?
        ShoppingCart.map((products)=>(
          <div>
            <span><img style={Style} src={products.image}></img></span>
            <span>{price}</span>
            <span>{quantity}</span>
            <span><button id={products.id} onClick={updatevalue}>+</button></span>
          </div>
        ))
      :''}
    </div>
  )
}
export default Cart
```

Comment: yup it work actually i was updatting price instead of saving and using prev state

Comment: How do you know what the index is of the `price` array you want to update? Are you trying to also update the `price` property in the `ShoppingCart` array in the context? Why are you duplicating "state"? You should have a single source of truth. Why not just update the "state" in the context and rederive the `price` array when the context updates? Question seems a bit unclear.

Comment: based on my click button i will get the id of that product and will use that id to track my price array that i already make in useEffect

Comment: Yeah, I see that a bit better now... why not just pass the index used from `ShoppingCart.map` to the `updatevalue` callback? Skip the whole searching for matching `id` bit each time. If you wanted to stick to matching by `id` then the `ShoppingCart.map` in the handler should really be a `ShoppingCart.forEach` since you are really only iterating the cart array.

Comment: yeah i get your point already update that gives me answer great thanks Drew

Comment: i was also not using map that also my fault so anyone watching after that should map or forEach to access each index thanks to Drew for catching that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass the index to the `updatevalue` when the cart is mapped, and update the `price` array at that index. convert `updatevalue` to a curried function to consume the index and return the event handler.

```
const updatevalue = index => () => {
  setPrice(prices => prices.map((price, i) => i === index ? price * 2 : price));
}

...

return (
  <div className='container'>
    {ShoppingCart.map((products, i)=>( // <-- cart index
      <div>
        <span>
          <img style={Style} src={products.image} />
        </span>
        <span>{price}</span>
        <span>{quantity}</span>
        <span>
          <button onClick={updatevalue(i)}>+</button> // <-- pass index to handler
        </span>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
)
```